# How to use callback in JS (node) to wait for Async function to finish before proceeding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord.js, async.js

I have an function called translateCommand(command) that uses a Translate package from npm to translate some text into a different language. The problem is the translate function provided by that package is asynchronous and it tends to exit the translateCommand function before the translate function is finished, resulting in the return of garbage data.

I identified it finishing too fast as the issue and made translateCommand(command) an async function, so that I could use await in front of the imported translate() function, which solved that issue, but now I've simply delayed the issue a step further back because the function that calls translateCommand(command) is experiencing the exact same issue and I feel like I've made no headway if I'm just going to have to keep repeating this chain upward.

Fact of the matter is, I don't really understand Promises and how Async functions behave in general in relation to them. I realize this is a premise that makes Node.js great, but trying to learn about it has been fairly ineffective. Trying to solve this problem hasn't really bore fruit as everyone just says to use callback without explaining what exactly a callback is. It doesn't help that the examples were usually surrounded with unfamiliar code, so I figured getting help in the context of my code would tackle two birds with one stone.

This whole process is my introductory attempt to make a silly Discord Bot where I've implemented a bunch of silly features. I've ran into the Async wall many times, but usually found a Synchronous alternative to proceed forward. This time I did not, and I've tried to emulate callbacks described in other Stack Overflow posts, but due to a lack of understanding, was unable to integrate them correctly (I can only assume).

Top-level imported function that now has the Async issue.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {

    // ...
    let command = (message.content).substr(1);

    // ...

    // Handles translate command
    else if (command.startsWith("translate"))
        message.channel.send(translateCommand(command));

    // ...
    }
});
```

Function that was made async so it could await:

```
// Form !translate [string]
async function translateCommand(command) {
    let message = "";
    let str = command.substr(10);

    await translate(str, { to: 'ja', engine: 'yandex', key: '<my key>' }).then(function(result) {
        message = result;
        return "";
    });
    return message;
}
```

I'm aware this question has been asked to death, but I feel that without context I understand (as I'm still new to both JS and Node), I can only proceed by beating my head against a wall until something works without me understanding why.

Comment: `async (message) => {` and `message.channel.send(await translateCommand(command));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `translate` returns a promise you don't need to make `translateCommand` `async`. Simply return `translate` from the function...

```
function translateCommand(command) {
  let str = command.substr(10);
  return translate(str, { to: 'ja', engine: 'yandex', key: '<my key>' });
}
```

...and `await` the promise to resolve. You need to add `async` to the event handler callback for `await` to work.

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {

  let command = (message.content).substr(1);

  //...

  else if (command.startsWith("translate"))
    message.channel.send(await translateCommand(command));
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: So I can scrap the `.then(function(result) { message = result; return ""; })` part entirely? Also as a followup, how is it that the result parameter was capturing the output of translate anyways? Sorry and thank you so much.

Comment: Instead of `then` you could have used `const message = await translate(...)`, and then you would `return message`. But you can miss that step out and simply return the promise instead. In your code `result` is just the data (as argument) in the `resolve` function. It could have been named anything. Anyway, give it a test and see if it works for you.

Comment: PS. You can see the difference between `then` and `await` in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7knym9g/).

Answer (score 1):

You can change your top-level function to be async as well. Change the beginning to `async (message) => {` and use `message.channel.send(await translateCommand(command))`. Alternatively, you could opt to use promises and not make the function async, and instead use `translateCommand(command).then(msg => message.channel.send(msg))`, however it could mess up the flow later in the code.

Comment: `client.on("message", async (message) => {  // ...  }});`


Assuming this is the correct implied structure, suggested by the first method (correct me if I'm wrong). Are there any consequences to other synchronous functions in this top-level function that will be using message? Also what do you mean by the Promise route potentially messing up the flow later in the code? Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using promises, you could do the following:

`translateCommand` function:

```
var translateCommand = (command) => new Promise((resolve,reject) =>  {
    translate(command.substr(10), { to: 'ja', engine: 'yandex', key: '<my key>' })
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject)
    });
```

then `client.on`:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {

    // ...
    let command = (message.content).substr(1);

    // ...

    // Handles translate command
    else if (command.startsWith("translate"))
        translateCommand(command)
            .then(translationResult => {
               message.channel.send(translationResult)
            })
    // ...
    }
});
```

If you have troubles with the syntax, here are the hints:
[hint #1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
[hint #2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
+ One remark - don't be afraid and take your time to read + implement the above examples and modify them afterwards to cause errors (you will know how and when they do or do not work - painful but rewarding ;) )

Comment: Thank you for providing another approach! It really helps to see all the ways to solve this problem, also embarrassingly validates my confusion on the topic as I think I tried pieces of all of these solutions mixed together. Following your hints, I just realized why I was getting so confused with arrow functions (they're basically Lambda Functions right?), it's cause if they have a single parameter, you can remove the parenthesis surrounding the parameter, which confused me eternally.

Comment: It has been a very long time since I touched C#, but yes, I think the `fat arrow functions` (since they have that funny name in javascript) can be perceived as `lambda expressions` (at least in this case). I'm happy I could help. Also -  yes, when they take single parameter, the parentheses can be omitted (one little downside is that it introduces code readability 'difficulties' [non unified syntax] when declaring multiple functions with different number of parameters).

Comment: The key difference between normal functions and arrow functions is that arrow functions don't have their own `this` or `arguments`. They inherit their `this` from the outer lexical environment which saves on assigning `this` to `self`, or binding.

Comment: @Andy: no one mentioned `'normal' functions`, but `lambda` and `arrow` ones

Comment: And I explained the difference between them. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that your comment is unrelated.